# Multiple applications in same ec2 instance on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I have 2 docker applications that expose an HTTP service on port 8080 (totally different apps). Today in AWS beanstalk I have the following configuration:

```
 - Application A
   --> Environment Staging (EC2 t2.micro instance-1)
   --> Environment Production (EC2 t2.micro instance-2)

 - Application B
   --> Environment Staging (EC2 t2.micro instance-3)
   --> Environment Production (EC2 t2.micro instance-4)
```

As you can see, I have 4 ec2 t2.micro instances. My project should be very cost-effective, so my customer request a change to use only 1 EC2 instance t3a.medium. So, I'm thinking in the following structure:

```
 - Application A
   --> Environment Staging (EC2 t3a.micro instance-1)
   --> Environment Production (EC2 t3a.micro instance-1)

 - Application B
   --> Environment Staging (EC2 t3a.micro instance-1)
   --> Environment Production (EC2 t3a.micro instance-1)
```

But, I don't know if this is possible in Beanstalk, I can't find a way to choose the same ec2 instance when creating a new Application. Is this possible?

I'm thinking to move to ECS Cluster service, but before the move, I would like to be sure that I can't do it in beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but in the EB you can have [multidocker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html) environments:

> You can create docker environments that support **multiple containers per Amazon EC2 instance** with multicontainer Docker platform for Elastic Beanstalk.

In fact EB is using ECS in the backend for that:

> Elastic Beanstalk uses Amazon Elastic Container Service (**Amazon ECS**) to coordinate container deployments to multicontainer Docker environments.

Thus if you are contemplating the use of ECS, you can use it through EB. This may save you some time on setting up everything yourself.

Comment: I tried to use "multidocker strategy" but I didn't found where I can't point to same EC2 in different EB application.